# What's the action of banging two beers together called?

Tags: single-word-requests

When beers in cans or bottles are banged together in rejoice of the company you're with, what is the action called?

Comment: a toast?  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toast (noun, definition 3)

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. Questions are expected to show considerable evidence of research and be of interest to language experts (professionals and enthusiastic amateurs). There may be some overlap with enthusiastic drinkers, but not necessarily. Thanks.

Comment: If it's vigorous enough, it can be called "wrist-drenching."

Answer (score 13):

They [**clinked** their bottles](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22clinked%20their%20bottles%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). From thefreedictionary:

> [**clink**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clink) - make a high sound typical of glass; *"champagne glasses clinked to make a toast"*

Less commonly, [they **chinked** bottles](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22clinked%20their%20bottles%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22they%20chinked%20bottles%22&oq=%22they%20chinked%20bottles%22&gs_l=serp.3...54386.57286.1.57574.11.11.0.0.0.2.155.938.7j4.11.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.PLluEzintos&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1308&bih=844). All variants are often followed by the word *together*.

Because *cans* don't really make quite the same sound, I might say *clunked* or *clonked* or *clanked* instead if cans were involved. Those vowels suggest a somewhat lower note when struck together.

EDIT: *clanked* borrowed from [@cynthia-hartwig's](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/39390/cynthia-hartwig) deleted answer. Can't think of everything!

Comment: Yes. You *clink* them, or *clink* them *together*.

Comment: @MετάEd: That would be visible to anyone who looked at the first page of Google Books results in the link, but you're right - I should explicitly mention it.

Comment: What if you've got shandy in plastic bottles?

Comment: @Edwin: Only [Billy No Mates](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22billy+no+mates%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) drinks shandy in plastic bottles, so the issue doesn't arise! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: indisputable logic.

Answer (score 4):

"They clanked beers" or "They clanked their tankards," along with the following toast:

> For every wound, a balm.
>
> For every sorrow, cheer.
>
> For every storm, a calm.
>
> For every thirst, a beer.

Comment: I swiped "clanked" because the answer was deleted (I don't know why), and thus most people wouldn't be able to see it (you need quite a high rep score on SO to be able to see deleted answers). But it's a perfectly credible usage - witness half-a-dozen written instances of [{they} clanked cans {and drank}](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22clanked+cans%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). So have an upvote in return for my plagiarism!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'll clank to that....

Comment: @J.R, Cynthia: [chin-chin!](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chin-chin). I would have said *chink-chink*, but I've just discovered from that link it may have a Chinese origin anyway, so I'm leery of pejorative overtones I never previously knew about.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _chin-chin_ also happens to be Japanese slang for _penis_ :)

Answer (score 1):

A [cheers](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cheers): "a drinking toast,"

or

a [toast](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toast): "The act of raising a glass and drinking in honor of or to the health of a person or thing."

Comment: Please add the relevant definitions to your answer.