# A term in English for when you "clink" (?) or touch glasses together

Tags: single-word-requests

I was out for a meal with a few Spanish friends of mine and at one stage during the evening we all "clinked" (?) or touch our glasses together.  This is something that is usually done after someone makes a toast.

I was then asked what the term for this was in English and I didn't know.  There is a term in Spanish for this, but I am not aware of one in English.

I have asked a few people and some people have suggested "A toast" but I do not believe this is the case.

Can anyone help me with what this is called?

Comment: [What's the action of banging two beers together called?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107056/whats-the-action-of-banging-two-beers-together-called/107058#107058)

Comment: I just saw that one myself! looks like that's probably the answer so.

Comment: Just curious, what's the term in Spanish?

Comment: @Matt: "To clink (glasses)" is "chocar (las copas)" in Spanish.

Comment: Just FYI @AidanO "chink" (a crack, like in a wall, or in armor) is also a derogatory term for an Asian or Chinese, specifically, so I would avoid using that word for the action of "cheers"ing or toasting even if it were the right spelling!

Comment: @TylerH's comment needs more attention.  I would try to avoid using that word in nearly all circumstances.

Comment: Rhett and Link (from Good Mythical Morning, among others) say "dink it." While not authoritative in any sense (and unique to them, as far as I can tell), it's worth a mention :).

Comment: In french it's "trinquer" and the origin of the action is said to come from the middle ages where you would smash your drinks/glasses hard enough for the liquids to mix with eachother, showing your confidence in your guest, and in the fact that he didnt poison your drink.

Comment: In the navy clinking a grog glass was forbidden as it implied the death of a sailor

Comment: @TylerH spelling adjusted, no offense obviously intended.

Answer (score 33):

The term I've always heard used for this is [clinking](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/clink_1?q=clink) glasses.

> [intransitive, transitive] to make or cause something to make a sharp
>   ringing sound, like that of glasses being hit against each other
>   
> SYNONYM **chink**
>
> - *clinking coins*
> - *The coins clinked into the slot in the machine.*
> - **clink something** *They clinked glasses and drank to each
>     other's health.*

—Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary

Here's a quote from the "Ettiquette International" web page about [toasting](http://www.etiquetteinternational.com/articles/toasting.aspx), which uses the word:

> End on a positive note. A toast should always be upbeat. Lead your
>   audience to a conclusion with a generally accepted gesture like "Raise
>   your glass" or **clinking.**

Answer (score 2):

A toast means you lift up your glass and say something to those present. And it may not include clinking/touching glasses at all. 
Similarly, you can clink glasses with someone, and have no toast at all.
Clinking glasses means you lightly touch your glass to someone else's glass.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, [***toast glasses***](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/toast%20glasses)

> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22toasted+glasses%22&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilhrDTi8jKAhUFtRoKHUccAaQQ_AUIDCgG)
>
> [Google Image](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22toast+glasses%22&biw=380&bih=251&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie146YjsjKAhUK8RQKHSilCGEQ_AUIBigB)